# Any drawbacks to referencing multiple tables from a single column?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, constraint, referential-integrity, composite-types

I'm working on a system with the following entities:

- Projects
- Sections
- Activities

There is one important constraint that needs to be enforced:

**`Activities` are *always* part of one `project`. `Activities` can also be part of one `section`, but only if that `section` is part of the `activity's` `project`**.

I came up with the following solution:

[image: Schema]

One FK is a reference from `activities.projects_id` to `projects.id`.

The other (composite) FK is a reference from `activities.projects_id, activities.sections_id` to `sections.projects_id, sections.id`. The column `activities.sections_id` is NULLable.

The table `sections` has a composite PK of `id, projects_id`.

The solution seems to do exactly what I want. I assume that the constraint on `activities.project_id` is satisfied when either `projects.id` or `sections.projects_id` has a value? Any light on this?

Are there any drawbacks to this solution? Any improvements or alternatives I'd need to consider?